# What does $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$(y) mean?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

What does $x$ $\in$ field $\mathbb{Q}$(y) mean?
What is $\mathbb{Q}$(10), for instance?

Comment: Chances are that in this context, $y$ is not a variable (which may be evaluated to anything in $\mathbb Q$) but an indeterminate, that is, an element transcendental over $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is the smallest extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is still a field and which contains $x$. For example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) = \{ a + b \sqrt{2} : a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$.

Let's check the closure properties for this example. Addition and subtraction are the easy part: you add and subtract "componentwise", getting

$$(a + b \sqrt{2}) \pm (c+ d \sqrt{2}) = (a \pm c) + (b \pm d) \sqrt{2}.$$

For multiplication, we can expand:

$$(a+b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{2}) = ac+2bd+(ad+bc)\sqrt{2}.$$

For division, we can rationalize the denominator:

$$\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}} = \frac{a}{a^2-2b^2}-\frac{b}{a^2-2b^2} \sqrt{2}.$$

So this is a field extension. To see that it is the smallest one, note that if $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ then we must have $b \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ (for closure under multiplication) and must have $a+b\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ (for closure under addition). So any other extension which contains $\sqrt{2}$, must contain this one, i.e. this is the smallest such extension.

In this sense $\mathbb{Q}(10)$ is just $\mathbb{Q}$. In certain contexts it could be a nontrivial extension, but this is abuse of notation, so some context would be required to be sure.

Comment: General rule: don't use words like "obviously" when explaining something. (Besides for that, great answer.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw How's the edited version? I personally find it helpful to have some indication of which parts of a large problem are easy and which parts are hard. Perhaps this phrasing is less condescending about it?

Comment: Seems good. (That rule isn't something I made up, by the way…)

Comment: @columbus8myhw I know. This is a common problem in the mathematical literature. I grapple with it both as a reader and as a writer. It can be tricky to tell the reader when something is easy while not making those who do not find it easy to feel discouraged. I agree that "this is easy" is better than "this is obvious".

Answer (score 2):

It could be any number of things, but if the $y$ is an integer, then $\mathbb{Q}(y)$ probably means the cyclotomic extension of that order.  So $\mathbb{Q}(10)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ for $\zeta$ a primitive tenth root of unity.

Comment: Huh, I've never seen that notation for cyclotomic extensions...do you know of a source that uses this notation?

Comment: I cannot remember any written source (maybe lecture notes?) but we have used this abbreviation a lot in the algebraic number theory courses I have taken.  I had assumed this is where the OP's $Q(10)$ came from, otherwise it makes little sense to talk about it, but it seems I misunderstood and the OP just wrote $10$ for example of an arbitrary algebraic number.